# get current value dropdown from state

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I need to get the selected current value from the state to the function, but it doesn’t work out for me what I do wrong

```
<Dropdown
  placeholder="Select Friend"
  fluid
  selection
  options={accountsList}
  value={accountsList.value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>

// onChange function 
onChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ value })

// function where i need to get value
const acc = this.state.accountsList.value
const year = this.state.years.value
const months = this.state.months.value
axios
  .get(`http://******/cabinet/invoice/${acc}/${year}/${months}`,
```

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete, example so that it will be easier for someone to help you. This code would not compile, e.g. onChange is not passed to a component.

Comment: Show what library for Dropdown are you using

Comment: i use react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without complete and minimalistic code my best guess is that you call the wrong function `onChange` in the `Dropdown` component. You also need to retrieve the value pass to on change via `event.target.value`.

Since you update the state of a nested object, `value` is a child of `accountsList` you have to deep clone it.

Like this:

`this.setState({ accountsList: { ...this.state.accountsList, value: newValue} });`

**In your example:**

```
<Dropdown
      placeholder="Select Friend"
      fluid
      selection
      options={accountsList}
      value={accountsList.value}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
/>

handleChange = (event) => {
     this.setState({ accountsList: { ...this.state.accountsList, value: event.target.value} });
};
```

Comment: Oh, it's cool, thanks, but now how can I pull the current value out of the state and send it to the backend?

Comment: It's stored in your state. Just like you're doing it now: `const acc = this.state.accountsList.value`. And send it via your axios call.

Comment: I seem to understand, but now he gives me an error
 Failed prop type: Invalid prop `options` of type `object` supplied to `Dropdown`, expected an array.
example my state

Answer (score 0):

I dare say that the *selected current value* would more likely exist in `onChange = ({value}) => this.setState({value})`, ie: It;ll be in the first argument of the callback, rather than the second.

What is the dropdown library?

Comment: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/
if I do the console in the onChangefunction, then in the console I will get the current value, but I need to give the current value to the server